# Issue resolving all promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a code block where I want to concatenate results of two database queries. So I tried implementing Promises.all

```
 const promise_list = []
let appData = [];
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let database = new Database();
    database.query(`select * from configuration where  version = (select max(version) from configuration) OR version= ? ORDER BY version `, [req.body.app_version])
        .then(rows => {
            appData=rows[0];
            database.close()
            resolve()
        }, err => {
            return database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json("Database Error");
            reject()
        })
});
promise_list.push(promise)
let promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let database = new Database();
    database.query(`select points from users where id=?`, [req.user.id])
        .then(rows => {
            appData.points=rows[0]['points'];
            database.close()
            resolve()
        }, err => {
            return database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json("Database Error");
            reject()
        })
});
promise_list.push(promise2)
Promise.all(promise_list).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json(appData);
});
```

The second query works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt. What could be the issue?

Comment: what do you mean _The second query works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt_ ? Does it throw an error? Whats the expected  and actual behavior?

Comment: *"The second query works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt."* What exactly does that mean? What happens when it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! And don't do `res.status(500)` twice - do it once in the end.

Comment: Call database.close in your promise.all callback not each query call

Comment: @AyushGupta  second query appends data to appData variable, sometimes its not there

Comment: @FelixKling  second query appends data to appData variable, sometimes its not there

Comment: `appData.points=rows[0]['points'];` only works if `appData` has been initialized by the other promise. But with `Promise.all`, either promise can be resolved first. If you need them to resolve in order, then you should do `promise1.then(() => /*promise2 stuff */).then(...)` instead. If they can run in parallel, just have each of them resolve properly, don't try to make them share an object.

Comment: @FelixKling got it. so in cases where I dont get points is because second promise resolved first right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appData.points=rows[0]['points'];` only works if `appData` has been initialized by the other promise first. But with `Promise.all`, either promise can be resolved first. If the first promise resolve second, it will simply override whatever value `appData` currently has.

It looks like you are using promises incorrectly. Instead of using them with side-effects (assigning to `appData`), you should resolve them properly.

The whole code can be cleaned up a lot to something like this:

```
let database = new Database();
let promise = database.query(`select * from configuration where  version = (select max(version) from configuration) OR version= ? ORDER BY version `, [req.body.app_version])
  .then(rows => rows[0]);
let promise2 = database.query(`select points from users where id=?`, [req.user.id])
  .then(rows => rows[0].points);

Promise.all([promise, promise2])
  .then(
    ([appData, points]) => {
      appData.points = points;
      res.status(200).json(appData);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      database.close().then(() => {
        res.status(500).json("Database Error");
      });
    }
  );
```

Don't know what `Database` does, so it's not clear whether it's OK to only call it once. But it should you a better idea for how to use promises.